# Bootstrap, I created a dropdown menu, how can I highlight choices on hover?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created a dropdown menu that opens when you click on a text box, and then when you chose a string for that dropdown list, it puts it in the text box.
I would like to make that when you hover your mouse on the strings in the dropdown, they get slightly highlighted!  how can I achieve this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 max300" uib-dropdown is-open="vm.descriptionDropdownOpen">
         <textarea name="remarks" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.presence.description" ng-click="vm.toggleDescriptionDropdown()" autofocus></textarea>
         <ul id="descriptionDropdown" uib-dropdown-menu>
             <li ng-repeat="descr in vm.loadedDescriptions" ng-click="vm.presence.description = descr.text; vm.descriptionDropdownOpen = false;">
                 {{descr.text}}
             </li>
         </ul>
```

and the css to keep the dropdown aligned with the textbox:

```
#descriptionDropdown {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: use `li:hover` property in your `css`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
#descriptionDropdown li:hover{
   background-color:#eaeaea;
}
```

Change the color code to your desired color code.
And remove the `padding` from `ul` to avoid space around background when you hover. Instead, use `padding` on `li`

```
#descriptionDropdown li{
   padding-left:8px;
}
```

Comment: it works but as I put some padding to the text, to avoid having the strings attached to the border, the highlight starts from the text and not from the left border of the dropdown menu! how can I make it start from the border?

Comment: i think you have tried to add padding on `ul` element. Instead of that use padding on `li`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: i have update my answer, remove padding from `#descriptionDropdown` and add it as i specified in my answer. and you could also use `text-align:center` to align text to center in dropdown,

Comment: alright!! please mark it as correct answer then if it was helpful.

Comment: How do I do that? (From mobile, can’t find any button to do that)

Answer (score 0):

You could add this css :

```
li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```